# No wifi on my dlink dir-655

Tags: router

I am having a problem with my dlink dir-655.
Not any of my devices can see the wifi. I have set it up using a network cable and the router says it is broadcasting wireless signal but not any of my devices can see it. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled "Enable SSID Broadcast" or something similar?

Try to manually type your Wireless network name into your device and see if it picks it up. Another issue could be your using 5GHz rather than 2.4Ghz, which isn't compatible with many devices at the moment.